# In ASP.net I want to setting some value into a textbox and then get the value in server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

It is my Code. And i have to use the plug in.

This is the plug-in website:http://jscolor.com/download/

It just a color picker plug-in.

```
MyCode:
<div class="FormItem">
<asp:Label ID="lblColor" runat="server">Color : </asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="rColor" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
<input ID="txtColor" class="jscolor {onFineChange:'update(this)'}"readonly="readonly" ></input>
```

This is the Function which update the color and text of the textBox.

```
function update(jscolor) {
    document.getElementById('<%=rColor.ClientID%>').style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor;
    document.getElementById('<%=rColor.ClientID%>').value = '#' + jscolor;   
}
```

How can i get the value of the TextBox in the server site.

I have tried to get rColor.Text in server site. It show me nothing inside of the TextBox(rColor).

This is my Server site Get value of TextBox code:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + rColor.Text + "');", true);

 project.Color = rColor.Text;
```

This still show the color which is Page_Load function load the value from database.

Comment: What is your server side code where you are trying to get the value of rColor?

Comment: And remove `ReadOnly="true"`, it will work then.

Comment: Thanks a lot but it cannot get the value

Comment: Then there is still a mistake somewhere. Give rColor a default Text and see if you can get that value. `<asp:TextBox ID="rColor" runat="server" Text="Test Content"></asp:TextBox>`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because of setting the textbox as readonly.

Refer this issue [textbox value change not being reflected in code behind c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847635/textbox-value-change-not-being-reflected-in-code-behind-c-sharp)